# R foreach parallel and package variables

Tags: r, r-package, parallel-foreach

I have the following code where i get an error like:

`object 'a' could not be found`

This file is inside a package.

It works when i use `%do%` instead of `%dopar%`

```
a <- 2

fun1 <- function(x)
{
  y <- x*a
  return(y)
}

fun2 <- function(n)
{
  foreach(data = 1:n, .combine = rbind, .multicombine = TRUE, .export = c("a","fun1")) %dopar%
  {
    load_all() # Works, get error if line is removed
    y <- fun1(data)
    return(y)
  }
}
```

In my main file where i use `devtools::load-all()` to load the package and have used `doParallel` to run my foreach on multiple cores i execute `fun2(5)` when getting the error.

If i use `a` directly in the foreach function body everything works. But when i use a function that uses the `a` variable, i get the error.

My main issue is i wan't to be able to call the function `fun1` from both `fun2` aswell as stand alone from the package.

Cluster is created as

```
  cl <- makeCluster(16)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  clusterCall(cl, function(x) .libPaths(x), .libPaths())

# %dopar% code

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: It works on my computer. How did you registered your parallel backend? Also side effect is a bad pratice. Try with a proper function such as `fun1 <- function(x, a)`

Comment: The code do not have side effects. The `a` variable is a const variable used across many functions inside the package.

Comment: Does it works if you run the foreach loop outside `fun2`? What is your OS? On My linux machine your code works (I checked the doc, by default it use PSOCK clusters like on Windows)

Comment: @JRR I'm on windows. It works if i load my own package using load_all() inside the foreach.

Comment: @CodeMonkey , see if this explanation helps: <https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2020/02/changes-in-the-foreach-package.html>